# Determinant Inequality with unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, matrix-theory

I come up with the following conjecture while doing my research, which is a determinant inequality.
I have tried to run the MatLab simulation to verify its sanity. It seems that the inequality is true. However, I couldn't prove it rigorously yet. Any idea would be appreciated.

Problem. Given a diagonal matrix $\Sigma = diag(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, unitary matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{ m \times n}$, and $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{ n \times n}$, where $\sigma_1 \geq \dots \geq \sigma_n > 0$, and $\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I}$. Prove that
$$\log_2\det\bigg(\mathbf{I}+\Sigma \mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{V}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{V}^H\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A} \bigg) \leq \log_2\det\bigg(\mathbf{I}+\Sigma \mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{A} \bigg), $$
where $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{ m \times n}$ satisfying $|V(i,j)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}
, \forall i,j$ ( each entry of $\mathbf{V}$ has modulus $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$). The equality holds iff $\mathbf{U} =\mathbf{V}$.

So far, I have proved that $\log_2\det\bigg(\Sigma \mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{U}^H\mathbf{V}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{V}^H\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A} \bigg) \leq \log_2\det\bigg(\Sigma \mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^H\mathbf{A} \bigg)$ by using the Hadamard's inequality.

Comment: For a matrix $U$, what is (the notation) $U^H$?

Comment: $\mathbf{U}^H$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $ \mathbf{U}$